# Stacking Numpy arrays of different length using padding

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5])

l = [a,b]
```

I want a function `stack_padding` such that:

```
assert(stack_padding(l) == np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,0]])
```

Is there a standard way in numpy of achieving

EDIT: `l` could have potentially many more elements

Comment: I got this far....but depends you know which one is the ending shape you want. `b.resize(a.shape, refcheck=False)`  That will resize b to `[4,5,0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `itertools` and `column_stack`, `numpy.ndarray.resize` will also do the job perfectly. As mentioned by jtweeder, you just need to know to resulting size of each rows. The advantage to use `resize` is that `numpy.ndarray` is contiguous in memory. Resizing is faster when each row differs alot in size. The performance difference is observable between the two approaches.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import itertools

def stack_padding(it):

    def resize(row, size):
        new = np.array(row)
        new.resize(size)
        return new

    # find longest row length
    row_length = max(it, key=len).__len__()
    mat = np.array( [resize(row, row_length) for row in it] )

    return mat

def stack_padding1(l):
    return np.column_stack((itertools.zip_longest(*l, fillvalue=0)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_rows = 200
    row_lengths = np.random.randint(30, 50, size=n_rows)
    mat = [np.random.randint(0, 100, size=s) for s in row_lengths]

    def test_stack_padding():
        global mat
        stack_padding(mat)

    def test_itertools():
        global mat
        stack_padding1(mat)

    t1 = timeit.timeit(test_stack_padding, number=1000)
    t2 = timeit.timeit(test_itertools, number=1000)
    print('With ndarray.resize: ', t1)
    print('With itertool and vstack: ', t2)
```

The `resize` method wins in the above comparison:

```
>>> With ndarray.resize:  0.30080295499647036
>>> With itertool and vstack:  1.0151802329928614
```

Comment: there is a bug in the code: `max(it, key=len).__len__()` always returns `len(it)`

Comment: @Jsevillamol It is supposed to return the length of the longest row in `it`. I ran several tests on my machine and it seemed to work correctly. What is `it` in your situation? A python `list` or `numpy.ndarray`? p.s. It should work with both the two types though..

Comment: oops my bad! I made a typo when writing your code. Thanks for the huge help and thorought analysis!

Comment: In the def resize function, i had to pass in resize(size, refcheck=False) for the inplace resize operation

Answer (score 6):

I think `itertools.zip_longest` with `fill_value=0` can work for you:

```
import itertools

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5])

l = [a,b]

def stack_padding(l):
    return np.column_stack((itertools.zip_longest(*l, fillvalue=0)))

>>> stack_padding(l)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 0]])
```

Comment: This is cool! Though it is a bit awkward that we need to transpose the result

Comment: @user3483203, I thought of that too, but then you add a dimension, so you also need to call `squeeze` or something like that : `np.dstack((itertools.zip_longest(*l, fillvalue=0))).squeeze()`

Comment: `column_stack` is `dstack` without adding the dimension

Comment: Ahh! That makes sense! Thanks @user3483203!

Comment: Transpose of an array is trivial.  But `np.stack(list(zip_longest...)), axis=1)` gives more control over the orientation.

Answer (score 4):

With `numpy.pad`:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5])

l = [a,b]

max_len = max([len(arr) for arr in l])
padded = np.array([np.lib.pad(arr, (0, max_len - len(arr)), 'constant', constant_values=0) for arr in l])
```