# Stacking numpy arrays with padding

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of 32 numpy arrays, each of which has shape `(n, 108, 108, 2)`, where `n` is different in each array. I want to stack all of them to create a numpy array of shape `(32, m, 108, 108, 2)`, where `m` is the maximum among the `n`s, and the shorter arrays are padded with zeros.

How do I do this?

I asked [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53051560/stacking-numpy-arrays-of-different-length-using-padding/53052599?noredirect=1#comment93005810_53052599) yesterday, but the answers there seem to break when using deep arrays like in my case.

Concretely, I went with this solution in the end, which produced the cleanest code:

```
data = np.column_stack(zip_longest(*data, fillvalue=0))
```

But now it is throwing this error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: You got some good answers yesterday, and good examples of how to express and test the ideas.  Please follow those examples, and show us how you attempted to solve the new problem.  Dare I flag this with [mcve]?

Comment: One quick thought - you could reshape your arrays to 2d, (n, 108*108*2), and apply one of the 2d solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by break? Exception is thrown, not the wanted output?

Comment: @hpaulj I have added more detail as suggested

Comment: `zip_longest` will work, but requires the right `fillvalue.  Not an integer, but an array of the right shape (e.g. np.zeros((108,108,2))`)

Comment: @hpaulj that makes sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a godly answer in [this webpage](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-preparation-variable-length-input-sequences-sequence-prediction/).

The `pad_sequences` function is exactly what I needed.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
result = pad_sequences(imgs, padding='post')
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I needed to stack images with different width and padded with zeros to the left side.
for me this works well:

```
np.random.seed(42)
image_batch = []
for i in np.random.randint(50,500,size=10):
image_batch.append(np.random.randn(32,i))
for im in image_batch:
    print(im.shape)
```

> output: (32, 152)
>    (32, 485)
>    (32, 398)
>    (32, 320)
>    (32, 156)
>    (32, 121)
>    (32, 238)
>    (32, 70)
>    (32, 152)
>    (32, 171)

```
def stack_images_rows_with_pad(list_of_images):
    func = lambda x: np.array(list(zip_longest(*x, fillvalue=0))) # applied row wise
    return np.array(list(map(func, zip(*list_of_images)))).transpose(2,0,1)

res = stack_images_rows_with_pad(image_batch)

for im in rez:
    print(im.shape)
```

> output: (32, 485)
>   (32, 485)
>   (32, 485)
>   (32, 485)
>   (32, 485)
>   (32, 485)
>   (32, 485)
>   (32, 485)
>   (32, 485)
>   (32, 485)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# Create matrices with random first axis length.
depth = np.random.randint(3,20,size=32)
l = []
lmax = 0
for i in depth:
    l.append(np.ones((i,10,10,2)))
    lmax = i if i > lmax else lmax

# Join the matrices:
new_l = []
for m in l:
    new_l.append(np.vstack([m, np.zeros((lmax-m.shape[0], 10, 10, 2))]))
master = np.stack(new_l, axis=0)
master.shape
>>> (32, 19, 10, 10, 2)
```

I find `np.pad` almost impossible to work with on higher dimensional matrix - luckily, what you asked was simple, where only one of the dimension will have to extended, such that it's easy to use `np.vstack` to stack a zeros array that make it conform to a new shape.

Answer (score 0):

```py
A = np.ones((4,3))


border_top_bottom = np.zeros((A.shape[1])).reshape(1,A.shape[1])
print(np.vstack([border_top_bottom,A,border_top_bottom]))

temp = np.vstack([border_top_bottom,A,border_top_bottom])

border_right_left = np.zeros((temp.shape[0])).reshape(temp.shape[0],1)
print(np.hstack([np.hstack([border_right_left,temp,border_right_left])]))
```